# React-Query: callback after setQueryData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In a form, upon receiving a response from server, I update the cache using [setQueryData](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetquerydata). However, after the cache update, I want to trigger the form input field to be focused again.

Details:

In my React app, I am using [Recoil.js](https://recoiljs.org/) to manage the state. React-Query is used to fetch & cache the data. I normalise the data & store in Recoil state, to which the React components subscribe for update.

While React-Query's `setQueryData` is a synchronous function, however, the app `refresh` because of new data is not (& any call after the setQueryData is not actioned).

How can I trigger the form input focus after the refresh of cache?

Answer (score 0):

you can just call the focus function right after you call `setQueryData`, as it's synchronous:

```
setQueryData(key, newData)
focusField() //some function that focuses the field
```

alternatively, you can spawn a `useEffect` that always does something when data updates:

```
const { data } = useQuery(...)

useEffect(() => {
  focusField()
}, [data])
```